# Equivalent Hensel's lemma?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a complete field with nonarchimedian valuation $|\cdot|$ and $\mathcal{O}_K := \{x \in K: \; |x| \le 1\}$, $\mathfrak{m} := \{x \in K: \; |x| < 1\}$.

I have seen two statements that do not seem to be equivalent called Hensel's Lemma:

1: Let $f(X) \in \mathcal{O}_K[X]$, $f(X) \notin \mathfrak{m}[X]$ such that $[f] = \overline{g} \cdot \overline{h}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K[X]/\mathfrak{m}$. Then there exist polynomials $g,h \in \mathcal{O}_K[X]$ with $f = gh$ and $\mathrm{deg}(g) = \mathrm{deg}(\overline{g})$ and $[g] = \overline{g}, [h] = \overline{h}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K[X]/\mathfrak{m}$.

2: Let $f(X) \in \mathcal{O}_K[X]$ and $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $|f(\alpha)| < |f'(\alpha)|^2$. Then there exists some $\beta \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $f(\beta) = 0$ and $|\alpha - \beta| < |f'(\alpha)|$.

Does the first somehow imply the second?

Comment: Well, $f(\beta)=0\iff (x-\beta)\mid f(x)$, so there's that.

Comment: The two forms of Hensel's lemma you give are not equivalent, but they have the same general flavor. There is a form of this type of result that includes both as special cases, but in practice one of the versions you wrote is adequate. By the way, at the time I write this your first version is meaningless since the conclusion of it says nothing at all about $f(X)$.

Comment: @KCd You're right. It's supposed to say $f = gh$